# Unable to run anipose due to ImportError: cannot import name 'keras_export' from 'tensorflow.python.util.tf_export'

Tags: tensorflow, ubuntu, keras, anaconda

I've been attempting to install and run anipose in Ubuntu 18.04
I keep getting the same import error though I've made sure keras is installed.
I've also searched for version compatibility because in the anipose environment setup tensorflow version is set to 1.13.1, though I see when I install everything it downloads tensorflow 2.8.0

```
(anipose) nimrod@msi-ubuntu:~/anipose_projects/hand-demo-unfilled$ anipose run-all
Analyzing videos...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nimrod/anaconda3/envs/anipose/bin/anipose", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli())
  File "/home/nimrod/anaconda3/envs/anipose/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1130, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/nimrod/anaconda3/envs/anipose/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1055, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/nimrod/anaconda3/envs/anipose/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1657, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/home/nimrod/anaconda3/envs/anipose/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1404, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/home/nimrod/anaconda3/envs/anipose/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 760, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/nimrod/anaconda3/envs/anipose/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 84, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/nimrod/anaconda3/envs/anipose/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 760, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/nimrod/anaconda3/envs/anipose/lib/python3.7/site-packages/anipose/anipose.py", line 365, in run_all
    pose_videos_all(config)
  File "/home/nimrod/anaconda3/envs/anipose/lib/python3.7/site-packages/anipose/common.py", line 168, in fun
    return process_all(config, process_session, **args)
  File "/home/nimrod/anaconda3/envs/anipose/lib/python3.7/site-packages/anipose/common.py", line 153, in process_all
    output[past_folders] = process_session(config, path, **args)
  File "/home/nimrod/anaconda3/envs/anipose/lib/python3.7/site-packages/anipose/pose_videos.py", line 56, in process_session
    import deeplabcut
  File "/home/nimrod/anaconda3/envs/anipose/lib/python3.7/site-packages/deeplabcut/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "/home/nimrod/anaconda3/envs/anipose/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "/home/nimrod/anaconda3/envs/anipose/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 82, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import keras
  File "/home/nimrod/anaconda3/envs/anipose/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras import activations
  File "/home/nimrod/anaconda3/envs/anipose/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/activations.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras.utils.generic_utils import deserialize_keras_object
  File "/home/nimrod/anaconda3/envs/anipose/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras.utils.multi_gpu_utils import multi_gpu_model
  File "/home/nimrod/anaconda3/envs/anipose/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/multi_gpu_utils.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras.engine.training import Model
  File "/home/nimrod/anaconda3/envs/anipose/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras.engine.base_layer import Layer
  File "/home/nimrod/anaconda3/envs/anipose/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 36, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras import initializers
  File "/home/nimrod/anaconda3/envs/anipose/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/initializers/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras.initializers import initializers_v1
  File "/home/nimrod/anaconda3/envs/anipose/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/initializers/initializers_v1.py", line 19, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.util.tf_export import keras_export
ImportError: cannot import name 'keras_export' from 'tensorflow.python.util.tf_export' (/home/nimrod/anaconda3/envs/anipose/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/tf_export.py)
(anipose) nimrod@msi-ubuntu:~/anipose_projects/hand-demo-unfilled$ conda list
# packages in environment at /home/nimrod/anaconda3/envs/anipose:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_libgcc_mutex             0.1                        main  
_openmp_mutex             4.5                       1_gnu  
_tflow_select             2.3.0                       mkl  
absl-py                   0.15.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0  
anipose                   1.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
aniposelib                0.4.3                    pypi_0    pypi
apptools                  5.1.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
argon2-cffi               21.3.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0  
argon2-cffi-bindings      21.2.0           py37h7f8727e_0  
astor                     0.8.1            py37h06a4308_0  
astunparse                1.6.3                    pypi_0    pypi
attrs                     21.4.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0  
backcall                  0.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
beautifulsoup4            4.11.1           py37h06a4308_0  
blas                      1.0                         mkl  
bleach                    4.1.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
brotli                    1.0.9                    pypi_0    pypi
bzip2                     1.0.8                h7b6447c_0  
c-ares                    1.18.1               h7f8727e_0  
ca-certificates           2022.3.29            h06a4308_1  
cached-property           1.5.2                      py_0  
cachetools                5.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
certifi                   2021.10.8        py37h06a4308_2  
cffi                      1.15.0           py37hd667e15_1  
charset-normalizer        2.0.12                   pypi_0    pypi
click                     8.1.2                    pypi_0    pypi
configobj                 5.0.6            py37h06a4308_1  
curl                      7.82.0               h7f8727e_0  
cycler                    0.11.0                   pypi_0    pypi
dataclasses               0.8                pyh6d0b6a4_7  
dbus                      1.13.18              hb2f20db_0  
debugpy                   1.5.1            py37h295c915_0  
decorator                 5.1.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
deeplabcut                2.2.1                    pypi_0    pypi
defusedxml                0.7.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
entrypoints               0.4              py37h06a4308_0  
envisage                  6.0.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
expat                     2.4.4                h295c915_0  
ffmpeg                    4.2.2                h20bf706_0  
filterpy                  1.4.5                    pypi_0    pypi
flask                     2.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
flask-compress            1.12                     pypi_0    pypi
flask-ipban               1.1.5                    pypi_0    pypi
flatbuffers               2.0                      pypi_0    pypi
fontconfig                2.13.1               h6c09931_0  
fonttools                 4.33.3                   pypi_0    pypi
freetype                  2.11.0               h70c0345_0  
future                    0.18.2                   py37_1  
gast                      0.5.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
glib                      2.69.1               h4ff587b_1  
gmp                       6.2.1                h2531618_2  
gnutls                    3.6.15               he1e5248_0  
google-auth               2.6.6                    pypi_0    pypi
google-auth-oauthlib      0.4.6                    pypi_0    pypi
google-pasta              0.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
grpcio                    1.42.0           py37hce63b2e_0  
gst-plugins-base          1.14.0               h8213a91_2  
gstreamer                 1.14.0               h28cd5cc_2  
h5py                      2.10.0           py37h7918eee_0  
hdf4                      4.2.13               h3ca952b_2  
hdf5                      1.10.4               hb1b8bf9_0  
icu                       58.2                 he6710b0_3  
idna                      3.3                      pypi_0    pypi
imageio                   2.18.0                   pypi_0    pypi
imgaug                    0.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
importlib-metadata        4.11.3           py37h06a4308_0  
importlib-resources       5.7.1                    pypi_0    pypi
importlib_metadata        4.11.3               hd3eb1b0_0  
importlib_resources       5.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1  
intel-openmp              2021.4.0          h06a4308_3561  
ipykernel                 6.9.1            py37h06a4308_0  
ipython                   7.32.0                   pypi_0    pypi
ipython_genutils          0.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1  
ipywidgets                7.6.5              pyhd3eb1b0_1  
itsdangerous              2.1.2                    pypi_0    pypi
jedi                      0.18.1           py37h06a4308_1  
jinja2                    3.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
joblib                    1.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
jpeg                      9e                   h7f8727e_0  
jsoncpp                   1.9.4                hff7bd54_2  
jsonschema                4.4.0            py37h06a4308_0  
jupyter                   1.0.0                    py37_7  
jupyter_client            7.2.2            py37h06a4308_0  
jupyter_console           6.4.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
jupyter_core              4.9.2            py37h06a4308_0  
jupyterlab_pygments       0.1.2                      py_0  
jupyterlab_widgets        1.0.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1  
keras                     2.8.0                    pypi_0    pypi
keras-applications        1.0.8                      py_1  
keras-base                2.3.1                    py37_0  
keras-preprocessing       1.1.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
kiwisolver                1.4.2                    pypi_0    pypi
krb5                      1.19.2               hac12032_0  
lame                      3.100                h7b6447c_0  
ld_impl_linux-64          2.35.1               h7274673_9  
libclang                  14.0.1                   pypi_0    pypi
libcurl                   7.82.0               h0b77cf5_0  
libedit                   3.1.20210910         h7f8727e_0  
libev                     4.33                 h7f8727e_1  
libffi                    3.3                  he6710b0_2  
libgcc-ng                 9.3.0               h5101ec6_17  
libgfortran-ng            7.5.0               ha8ba4b0_17  
libgfortran4              7.5.0               ha8ba4b0_17  
libgomp                   9.3.0               h5101ec6_17  
libidn2                   2.3.2                h7f8727e_0  
libnetcdf                 4.6.1                h11d0813_2  
libnghttp2                1.46.0               hce63b2e_0  
libogg                    1.3.5                h27cfd23_1  
libopus                   1.3.1                h7b6447c_0  
libpng                    1.6.37               hbc83047_0  
libprotobuf               3.19.1               h4ff587b_0  
libsodium                 1.0.18               h7b6447c_0  
libssh2                   1.10.0               h8f2d780_0  
libstdcxx-ng              9.3.0               hd4cf53a_17  
libtasn1                  4.16.0               h27cfd23_0  
libtheora                 1.1.1                h7f8727e_3  
libtiff                   4.1.0                h2733197_0  
libunistring              0.9.10               h27cfd23_0  
libuuid                   1.0.3                h7f8727e_2  
libvorbis                 1.3.7                h7b6447c_0  
libvpx                    1.7.0                h439df22_0  
libxcb                    1.14                 h7b6447c_0  
libxml2                   2.9.12               h03d6c58_0  
llvmlite                  0.38.0                   pypi_0    pypi
lz4-c                     1.8.1.2              h14c3975_0  
markdown                  3.3.4            py37h06a4308_0  
markupsafe                2.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
matplotlib                3.5.1                    pypi_0    pypi
matplotlib-inline         0.1.3                    pypi_0    pypi
mayavi                    4.7.1            py37h94891b3_2  
mistune                   0.8.4           py37h14c3975_1001  
mkl                       2021.4.0           h06a4308_640  
mkl-service               2.4.0            py37h7f8727e_0  
mkl_fft                   1.3.1            py37hd3c417c_0  
mkl_random                1.2.2            py37h51133e4_0  
mock                      4.0.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
msgpack                   1.0.3                    pypi_0    pypi
msgpack-numpy             0.4.7.1                  pypi_0    pypi
nbclient                  0.5.13           py37h06a4308_0  
nbconvert                 6.4.4            py37h06a4308_0  
nbformat                  5.3.0            py37h06a4308_0  
ncurses                   6.3                  h7f8727e_2  
nest-asyncio              1.5.5            py37h06a4308_0  
nettle                    3.7.3                hbbd107a_1  
networkx                  2.6.3                    pypi_0    pypi
notebook                  6.4.8            py37h06a4308_0  
numba                     0.55.1                   pypi_0    pypi
numexpr                   2.8.1                    pypi_0    pypi
numpy                     1.21.5           py37he7a7128_1  
numpy-base                1.21.5           py37hf524024_1  
oauthlib                  3.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
opencv-contrib-python     4.5.5.64                 pypi_0    pypi
opencv-python             4.5.5.64                 pypi_0    pypi
openh264                  2.1.1                h4ff587b_0  
openssl                   1.1.1n               h7f8727e_0  
opt-einsum                3.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
packaging                 21.3               pyhd3eb1b0_0  
pandas                    1.3.5                    pypi_0    pypi
pandocfilters             1.5.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
parso                     0.8.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
patsy                     0.5.2                    pypi_0    pypi
pcre                      8.45                 h295c915_0  
pexpect                   4.8.0              pyhd3eb1b0_3  
pickleshare               0.7.5           pyhd3eb1b0_1003  
pillow                    9.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pip                       21.2.2           py37h06a4308_0  
pip-autoremove            0.10.0                   pypi_0    pypi
prometheus_client         0.13.1             pyhd3eb1b0_0  
prompt-toolkit            3.0.29                   pypi_0    pypi
prompt_toolkit            3.0.20               hd3eb1b0_0  
protobuf                  3.19.1           py37h295c915_0  
psutil                    5.9.0                    pypi_0    pypi
ptyprocess                0.7.0              pyhd3eb1b0_2  
pyasn1                    0.4.8                    pypi_0    pypi
pyasn1-modules            0.2.8                    pypi_0    pypi
pycparser                 2.21               pyhd3eb1b0_0  
pyface                    7.3.0            py37h06a4308_1  
pygments                  2.12.0                   pypi_0    pypi
pyparsing                 3.0.8                    pypi_0    pypi
pyqt                      5.9.2            py37h05f1152_2  
pyrsistent                0.18.0           py37heee7806_0  
python                    3.7.13               h12debd9_0  
python-dateutil           2.8.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
python-fastjsonschema     2.15.1             pyhd3eb1b0_0  
pytz                      2022.1                   pypi_0    pypi
pywavelets                1.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pyyaml                    6.0                      pypi_0    pypi
pyzmq                     22.3.0           py37h295c915_2  
qt                        5.9.7                h5867ecd_1  
qtconsole                 5.3.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
qtpy                      2.0.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
readline                  8.1.2                h7f8727e_1  
requests                  2.27.1                   pypi_0    pypi
requests-oauthlib         1.3.1                    pypi_0    pypi
rsa                       4.8                      pypi_0    pypi
ruamel-yaml               0.17.21                  pypi_0    pypi
ruamel-yaml-clib          0.2.6                    pypi_0    pypi
scikit-image              0.18.1                   pypi_0    pypi
scikit-learn              1.0.2                    pypi_0    pypi
scikit-video              1.1.11                   pypi_0    pypi
scipy                     1.7.3            py37hc147768_0  
send2trash                1.8.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1  
setuptools                61.2.0           py37h06a4308_0  
shapely                   1.8.1.post1              pypi_0    pypi
sip                       4.19.8           py37hf484d3e_0  
six                       1.16.0             pyhd3eb1b0_1  
soupsieve                 2.3.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
sqlite                    3.38.2               hc218d9a_0  
statsmodels               0.13.1                   pypi_0    pypi
tables                    3.7.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tabulate                  0.8.9                    pypi_0    pypi
tbb                       2021.5.0             hd09550d_0  
tensorboard               2.8.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorboard-data-server   0.6.1                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorboard-plugin-wit    1.8.1                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow                2.8.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-base           1.13.1          mkl_py37h7ce6ba3_0  
tensorflow-estimator      1.13.0                     py_0  
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem 0.25.0                   pypi_0    pypi
tensorpack                0.11                     pypi_0    pypi
termcolor                 1.1.0            py37h06a4308_1  
terminado                 0.13.1           py37h06a4308_0  
testpath                  0.5.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
tf-estimator-nightly      2.8.0.dev2021122109          pypi_0    pypi
tf-slim                   1.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
threadpoolctl             3.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tifffile                  2021.11.2                pypi_0    pypi
tk                        8.6.11               h1ccaba5_0  
toml                      0.10.2                   pypi_0    pypi
tornado                   6.1              py37h27cfd23_0  
tqdm                      4.64.0                   pypi_0    pypi
traitlets                 5.1.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
traits                    6.2.0            py37h27cfd23_0  
traitsui                  7.2.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
typing-extensions         4.1.1                hd3eb1b0_0  
typing_extensions         4.1.1              pyh06a4308_0  
urllib3                   1.26.9                   pypi_0    pypi
vtk                       8.2.0           py37haa4764d_200  
wcwidth                   0.2.5              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
webencodings              0.5.1                    py37_1  
werkzeug                  2.0.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
wheel                     0.37.1             pyhd3eb1b0_0  
widgetsnbextension        3.5.2            py37h06a4308_0  
wrapt                     1.14.0                   pypi_0    pypi
wxpython                  4.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
x264                      1!157.20191217       h7b6447c_0  
xz                        5.2.5                h7b6447c_0  
yaml                      0.2.5                h7b6447c_0  
zeromq                    4.3.4                h2531618_0  
zipp                      3.7.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
zlib                      1.2.12               h7f8727e_2  
zstd                      1.3.7                h0b5b093_0
```

Tell me if there's any more information I can add

Comment: Try starting with a fresh environment. This one seems to have contradictions between the PyPI and Conda packages. E.g., `keras=2.8.0=pypi` doesn't jive with `keras-base=2.3.1`; nor `tensorflow=2.8.0=pypi` with `tensorflow-base=1.13.1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`anipose` supports Tensorflow 1.13.1.

```
pip install tensorflow==1.13.1
```

Below import works fine with Tf v2.8.0

```
from tensorflow.python.util.tf_export import keras_export
```

Make sure you have installed compatible version between anipose and Tensorflow.